# Validation with strong parameters on Input File Parameter in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, parameters

I'm building an API, and I need to create the following object:

```
certificate {
 file_name (String)
 file_p12  (binary) 
 password  (String) 
}
```

I'm sending by post the following parameters:

```
[
    {"key":"file_p12","value":{"0":{}}},
    {"key":"password","value":"1234"}
]
```

My model is:

```
class Certificate < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :file_name
    validates_presence_of :file_p12
    validates_presence_of :password
    belongs_to :api_client
end
```

In the controller, I'm saving the object in by this way:

```
@certificate = Certificate.create!([
  file_name: params[:file_p12].original_filename,
  file_p12: Base64.strict_encode64(params[:file_p12].read),
  password: params[:password],
  api_client_id: current_user.id])
```

My question is: How can I use a strong parameters to save that object, if I need to split the parameter "file_p12" to get the name and the byte info.

Comment: see https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters